# Change button text depending on IF condition

Tags: apex, visualforce, button

I am trying to set text on button depending on condition. If condition is true, Hello text should be displayed within button, otherwise - Goodbye.
This is what I tried.
Here is my component:

```
<button onClick="changeItemStatus('{!$Component.bVAL}', '{!item.Id}'); return false;" style="{!IF(orders[item.Id] > 0, '???', '???')}">Hello</button>
```

And this is what I want to use instead first ??? (if the condition is true):

```
button:after {
  content:'goodbye'; 
}
```

Or maybe here is another way to solve this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use CSS to do this, I'd just change the value in the content of the button:

```
<button onClick="changeItemStatus('{!$Component.bVAL}', '{!item.Id}'); return false;" >{!IF(orders[item.Id] > 0, 'Hello', 'Goodbye')}</button>
```